# Does IOS 5 support appearence APIs?

Tags: ios5

I’m busy making a customized table view app and was wondering if it will work with IOS 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS 5 is what brought in the appearance API's for UIKit ***Controls***

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iOS5.html

But for table views?  Depends on what you are trying to do.  If you are dropping controls into a custom cell, then "maybe".  :-)  Aside from "automatic row animations, moving rows and sections, multiselection, and copy and paste behaviors for cells", UITableView objects & functionality remain fundamentally the same.